# Was there a spike in hate crimes after the Brexit referendum?

Tags: criminology, united-kingdom, europe, brexit

Was there a spike in hate crimes after the Brexit referendum?

Example claim: ['Horrible spike' in hate crime linked to Brexit vote, Met police say](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2016/sep/28/hate-crime-horrible-spike-brexit-vote-metropolitan-police)

> A “horrible spike” in hate crime after Britain’s vote to leave the
>   European Union was at least partly linked to the referendum, Britain’s
>   most senior police officer has said.
>
> Sir Bernard Hogan-Howe, the Metropolitan police commissioner, told a
>   hearing at London’s City Hall that hate crime was showing signs of
>   decreasing after a sharp rise in June and July, but it had still not
>   returned to pre-referendum levels.

the article mentions statistics about a rise in the number of reports of hate crimes, but I couldn't see any mention of numbers of investigations, prosecutions or convictions, except for a single case in the last paragraph.

Comment: Come on. Sourced data is available in all the articles linked from the one you quoted for the claim, quoting [Home Office](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/oct/13/hate-crimes-eu-referendum-home-office-figures-confirm), [National Police Chiefs' Council](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2016/sep/07/hate-surged-after-eu-referendum-police-figures-show), ...

Comment: @DevSolar I think the point here is that data on *reported* hate crimes isn't particularly good evidence.  It's quite plausible that Brexit could lead to a change in reporting, because people might be more likely to interpret incidents as possible hate crimes given the atmosphere around Brexit.  Media narratives about a "spike in hate crimes" can also be self-fulfilling in terms of reports.

Comment: @dan1111: So you'd be looking for the number of *convictions*. Somewhat tricky when many of the cases have probably not even gone to court yet, hm?

Comment: @DevSolar the OP asked about "investigations, prosecutions or convictions".  It does seem likely that the question isn't going to be answerable, but I think the skepticism of the claim is warranted.

Comment: @dan1111: I'd assume that the numbers for *reported* crimes closely correlates to the one for *investigations* on those crimes, don't you?

Comment: @DevSolar: If you knew much about cops, you wouldn't assume that.

Comment: Neither number of investigations nor convictions will get you a watertight case: 'Investigations' will be launched in any reported case, thought the extent may be limited to writing down the report and then realising there is no cctv, no witnesses and the suspect is unknown and badly identifiable. According to https://www.cps.gov.uk/hate-crime 83% of the _prosecuted_ cases 2016 ended with a guilty verdict, so maybe you could tease something out of those numbers for the relevant time frames?

Answer (score 10):

[Research from the University of Southampton](http://blogs.lse.ac.uk/brexit/2018/03/19/hate-crime-did-spike-after-the-referendum-even-allowing-for-other-factors/) found a statistically significant link between the Brexit referendum and an increase in hate crimes.

The latest crime survey stats for hate crimes are only [available up to 2015](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/467366/hosb0515.pdf#page=19). However, it should be noted that the numbers in the survey tend to mirror the number of reported crimes, only a little higher, so in the absence of other evidence you would expect the trend to continue.

Comment: The researcher you linked also only used _reported_ crime - he controlled for other factors, like time of year and terrorism, but still uses reported crime (simply because we'll have to wait for the numbers of convictions to come in for some time still, and it is very unlikely that numbers on investigations will be useful either, because 'investigation' is just a name for  'unclosed case', not for 'something we take seriously and are actively engaged in solving', so whether an investigation is launched is influenced by many things, including political climate)

Comment: @bukwyrm what are you trying to say, that Brexit caused people to *report* more hate crime even though the actual amount didn't go up? And then again after the terror attacks? That seems unconvincing, especially compared to the research's hypothesis that increased negative framing of immigrants and immigration in the media is responsible for an actual rise in such crimes, with such framing being measurable.

Comment: imo reported crime is a good indicator for real crime. But the line of argument that you just mentioned (reports going up without crime going up because people feel jittery) is precisely the argument made (and referenced in the research you linked) by Daily Mail etc.  The OP specifically asked about data beyond the reports for (probably) that reason.

Comment: the problem with reported crime is some papers (e.g. the Guardian) pushed a heavy 'Brexit is about racism' line, which would encourage reporting (and potentially offences, ironically)

Comment: @Orangesandlemons it was probably more to do with some papers (like the Daily Mail) pushing an extreme anti-immigrant line, which would encourage hate crime. UKIP recycling Nazi propaganda probably didn't help either.

Comment: @dont_shog_me_bro possibly (although that would be an increase in actual and I'm purely pointing out an issue with using reported), but also I was struck that the claim is _after_ the vote, rather than in the run up, when said agenda was being pushed. Of course, it could be a sort of 'victory' feeling for those sorts.

Comment: @dont_shog_me_bro Good artists copy. Great artists steal.-Hitler,  probably

Comment: @Orangesandlemons after is what I'd expect, the victor gave bigots permission to act out their hatred because they thought they were in the majority and their views had become mainstream. Sadly I think they might not have been entirely wrong.

Comment: @dont_shog_me_bro It seems to me quite plausible that the campaign and result would encourage more hate crime *but* it also seems quite plausible that they might result in a high fraction of such crimes being reported - that is why a report based on reported crime is not as convincing as one on actual.